# How can I not allow an element in an array to not increment if it was already incremented on that run in the loop?

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the summary of CFG with given input.  I have to list the terminals with the count of how many times it appears in the rule.  However, I'm having trouble with it counting multiple terminals on the same rule.

```
for (int i = 0; i < cfg.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cfg[i].size(); j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < terminal.size(); k++)
        {
            if (strcmp(cfg[i][j].c_str(), terminal[k].c_str()) == 0)
            {
                //TO-DO if counter[k] already incremented do not increment counter[k] again
                counter[k]++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For example if the rule is

```
Z -> a b b b
```

It will return 3 for b when the correct answer would be 1.

Any help on how I can how I can leave that rule after it has already been counted would be great.  Thank you

Comment: Why `strcmp` if you have access to `std::string`?

Comment: If the goal is to not increment, why are you incrementing?  Just set `counter[k]` to 1.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: the goal is to increment every time that terminal ends up on the right hand side of the rule.  if the terminal appears multiple times, I should not increment if I had already counted for the first one.

Comment: @muchtolearn So why doesn't merely setting `counter[k]` to 1 not accomplish this goal?  You could see the symbol a thousand times, the value will still be 1.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie There could be another rule that has b and I would have to increment it to 2.  For example Z -> a b b b, X -> b C would return 2 for b

Comment: You asked how not to increment, but now you say you need to increment.  Which one is it?  Or maybe you should restate your issue more clearly (or rethink the way you designed your program / loops).

Comment: I need to increment as long as it hasn't incremented in the 3rd for loop.  I am trying to figure out how to leave that loop once counter[i] has incremented. If i leave the loop with a boolean check it won't iterate for the other terminals.  I was just wondering if there is a way to stop counting that specific terminal once it has already been tallied

Comment: There are probably much better ways to solve your issue than to write a triple nested loop.  You have a two dimensional vector of strings `cfg`, and a single vector of strings `terminal`.  Given only this information, what, on a high-level, are you trying to accomplish?  Don't mention "rules", "terminals", etc.

Comment: This is my first time using 2d vector so I thought the only way was to use a double for loop to iterate through it.  With just cfg and terminal I have to match elements that appear in both of them without repeats.  If there is a match, I increment a counter that corresponds to the spot of the terminal vector.  However, if it pops up more than once on that row I cannot count for it again.  The problem I am running into is leaving that 3rd loop early.  If i leave it early, there is a chance that there is a matching element after the position where I left the loop early.  Sorry if it looks messy.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have tried a different approach.  Is it possible to do sort and unique on a 2d string vector?  I have tried using the same method I used on a 1d vector but it is only deleting the first column.  If it is possible, it will remove all duplicates from cfg making it impossible to count the same element twice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand what you mean, but maybe changing the loops order would help?

```
for (int i = 0; i < cfg.size(); ++i)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < terminal.size(); ++k)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cfg[i].size(); ++j)
        {
            if (strcmp(cfg[i][j].c_str(), terminal[k].c_str()) == 0)
            {
                ++counter[k];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was approaching the entire problem incorrectly.  All I had to do was make sure the vectors I added to cfg did not have duplicates to avoid this problem.  Thank you though!

Comment: @muchtolearn Then you used the wrong STL container if you wanted no duplicates.  You should have used `std::set<std::string>` instead of `std::vector<std::string>`.  A `std::set` does not store duplicates.